# Extract A whole table from a different domain using javascript or html

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-scraping

Alright ive been working on a project and have ran into an issue, I am trying to extract a whole table from a different website, the website changes based on user input, here is my code. The table id on the 173.193.183.122 site is table 4 So basically I need when the person hits Set Vin and it gets loaded into setVin I need the decode vin button to open the 173.193.183.122 website into an iframe (right now its set to to iframe i ) and only display table 4 (its listed as table 4 in index when looking through the other websites source code) I would like to keep all my code in one file like it is now. please help me out I cant figure out after hours and hours of researching.

let me know thanks

```
<html>
<head>Plate Lookup<head>
<br> 
<TITLE>VIN</TITLE>
<BASE HREF="http://example.com/cfx/queryVin">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="vinDiv"> </div>
<script>
function setVin(){

myVin= document.forms["myform"]["text1"].value

} 
function test() {

iframe = document.getElementById('i');

iframe.src = 'http://173.193.183.122/VIN-Decoded/vin/'+myVin;

}

function setPlate(){

plate= document.forms["myform2"]["text2"].value;

} 


function setState(){

state= document.forms["myform3"]["text3"].value;

} 


function sPlate() {

iframe = document.getElementById('k');
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/cfx/queryVin?Plate=' + plate+'&State=' + state;

}


//-->

enter code here

</script>


<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="text1" value="Decode Vin">
<input type="button" value="Set Vin" onclick="setVin()">
</form> 

<form name="myform2">
<input type="text" name="text2" value="Type license plate here no spaces">
<input type="button" value="Set Plate" onclick="setPlate()">
</form> 

<form name="myform3">
<input type="text" name="text3" value="Type your 2 digit State code">
<input type="button" value="Set State" onclick="setState()">
</form> 

<a onclick="test()" target="i" onmouseover="test()"></a>
<iframe src="" id="i" name="i" width="700" height="400"  ></iframe>

<iframe src="" id="k" name="k" width="500" height="400"></iframe>

<br>
<button type="button" onclick="test()" >Decode Vin!</button> ^
<pre><pre>
<button type="button" onclick="sPlate()" >Decode plate!</button> ->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using iframes to access the DOM, cookies, etc, between different domains is always prevented for security reasons.

Using iframes to access this kind of data when both the host page and the page within the iframe are on the same domain is okay.